# Does a small opening in a supply duct exhaust or draw air?

Tags: vacuum

If I cut a neat 1 inch dia. hole in the 10" dia. supply air duct the new hole will act one way, ... or another. What determines if the new hole will act as a vacuum or a new push of air.

Comment: In a positive pressure duct you would have to insert something to get negative pressure at an orifice. Or I suppose you could deform the side of the duct. My heuristic is wind on a house: Pressure on the windward side, suction on the roof and leeward side. This is all for the laminar flow.

Comment: Please see take the [tour] to learn how this site works, then consider migrating some of the lengthy explanation below to your actual question post.

Answer (score 1):

A *supply* duct is under positive pressure - the air handler is *pushing* air out through the ductwork to the rest of the house. Air will go out from a hole in the ductwork. As an extreme, consider if you cut a hole the size of a typical air vent (e.g., 4" x 10") - you would expect air to come out of it. A 1" hole does the same thing, but at a smaller scale.

A *return* duct is under negative pressure - the air handler is *pulling* air from the rest of the house through the ductwork and back to itself for heating/cooling. Air will go in to a hole in the ductwork.

Comment: The fluid physics of the thing aren't quite that simple, but it's probably correct.

Comment: @isherwood Agreed. I thought about the more complex physics (which I vaguely understand, but I am not a physicist - too much math) but I came to the quick conclusion that at these scales (1" as opposed to perhaps tiny pinholes, typical residential HVAC air speed and pressure and not jet engines, etc.) air should basically behave pretty much normally.

Comment: In the course of installing and modifying duct work, especially the positive-pressure plenum right on top of an air handler, I've noticed that some gaps yield a leaking stream of air that can be sensed with a bare hand many inches away. The leakage through other gaps, often larger ones a foot or two away, might be barely perceptible. I've never tested whether one of those might be leaking _in_. That'll be interesting to test next time I have an opportunity.

Comment: The answers infer information lacking in my question. OK. this is the real question: 30-40 years ago we used to gather at the pool table in the basement of the in-laws house. Typical basement... cold, damp, drafty w/ extra refrig.holding ample beer near the pool table. One night the old man comes down and asked how the Hell we could play down there in the winter. He suggested one of us should cut a hole in the air supply duct in the ceiling just above the pool table (between the open exposed joists) and steal some heated air from the living room because no one was ever in the living room.

Comment: 2 - We cut the hole and thought it did something but over time realized that it did not do a tinkers damn. Put our hand near the hole and you could detect air movement. Over time we just accepted the fact that the only time the room appeared warmer was if you had 2-3 beers. This is way before that invented duct velocity measure device or smoke.  I always suspected the air movement felt was suction, ... NOT push air that we needed. I now have a basement work shop that is tolerable but in the winter I look at the air supply ducts heating the overhead kitchen and think of doing a simple hole.

Comment: 3 - I know I can lateral a new supply duct but was wondering, and being lazy, I thought I could get some good advice before moving ahead. Will the simple hole supply heat to the work area or suck the cold air out of the area?

Comment: It *should* blow out. But aside from the small (but non-zero) possibility that it will have the opposite effect due to *physics*, a 1" hole won't do much for you anyway. Consider a typical vent is on the order of 4" x 10" or sometimes more. If you want a useful amount of heat to come out, you need a typical size duct. Put one in that is fully adjustable - then when you aren't using the room you can close it off.

Comment: 4 - manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact ... Thanks for the informative answer. It is as I thought but this occasional/random reading of a vacuum caused by holes in long runs of active supply ducts had me confused.

Comment: "this is the real question", _please_ @BAB, edit your original question to actually ask the question you're after.

Answer (score 0):

In a supply duct, you'd get air blowing out of the hole *when the blower is running*. However, a 1" hole won't give you much air flow.

When the blower is *not* running, it's likely to suck some air in as the air in the ducts cools and starts to drop (due to gravity) back down to the lowest level in the house.